# Twitter Bootstrap progress bar with text in hero-unit is not displayed properly

Tags: text, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a problem with a standard Twitter Bootstrap progress bar with some text if it is within `<div class="hero-unit">`, also standard Twitter Bootstrap class:

```
<div class="hero-unit">
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 80%;">80%</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
​
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qe8K/) code, that shows the text is not aligned properly.
Why this is happening and how to fix? I've tried to fix it but had no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `line-height: 30px` on `hero-unit` which causes the problem.

I've change the code like this:

```
<div class="hero-unit" style="line-height: inherit">
```

Of course it is better to assign a class to it, instead of using the style attribute.